# Url changing when using PrivateRoute

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I have this PrivateRoute where if the user is authenticated, render that protected component, if not, redirect the user to the register page.

Now, it's working fine. If I'm logged in, the protected component( `post/new`) component renders but when I refresh, the `/register` component gets rendered.

```js
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, isAuthenticated, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        isAuthenticated ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/register"/>
        )
      }
    />
  );
};


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated};
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import LandingPage from "./components/LandingPage";
import RegistrationForm from "./components/RegistrationForm";
import LoginForm from "./components/LoginForm";
import NotFoundPage from "./components/NotFoundPage";
import Feed from "./components/Feed";
import { getCurrentUser } from "./actions/userActions";
import { addpost } from "./actions/userActions";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import NewpostForm from "./components/NewpostForm";
import Header from "../client/components/Header";
import UserProfile from "./components/UserProfile";
import PrivateRoute from "./components/PrivateRoute";
import ResetPasswordPage from "./components/ResetPasswordPage";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const authToken = localStorage.getItem("authToken");

    if (authToken) {
      this.props.dispatch({ type: "TOKEN_VERIFICATION_STARTS" });
      this.props.dispatch(getCurrentUser(authToken));
    }
  }

  render() {
    const isIdentifyingToken = this.props.auth.isIdentifyingToken;

    return (
      <div>
        {isIdentifyingToken ? null : (
          <Router>
            {/* <Header /> */}
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
              <Route path="/register" component={RegistrationForm} />
              <Route path="/login" component={LoginForm} />
              <Route path="/feed" component={Feed} />
              <PrivateRoute
                path="/post/new"
                component={NewpostForm}
              />
              <Route path="/profile" component={UserProfile} />
              <Route path="/reset-password" component={ResetPasswordPage} />
              <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return state;
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

**store.js**

```js
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from "redux"
import thunk from "redux-thunk"
import rootReducer from "./reducers/index"

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))


export default store
```

auth.js

```
const initialState = {
    isAuthInProgress: false,
    isAuthenticated: false,
    authError: null,
    user: null,
    isIdentifyingToken: false,
    token: localStorage.getItem("authToken") || ""
}


const auth = (state=initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "AUTH_STARTS":
            return {...state,
                 isAuthInProgress: true,
                 authError: null
            }

        case "AUTH_SUCCESS":
            return {...state,
                isAuthInProgress: false,
                authError: null,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                user: action.data.user,
                isIdentifyingToken: false,
                // token: action.data.token
            }

        case "AUTH_ERROR":
            return {...state,
                isAuthInProgress: false,
                authError: action.data.error,
                isAuthenticated: false,
                user: null
            }

        case "TOKEN_VERIFICATION_STARTS":
            return {...state,
                isAuthInProgress: true,
                authError: null,
                isIdentifyingToken: true
            } 

        case "LOGOUT_USER":
            return {...state,
            isAuthenticated: false,
            token: localStorage.removeItem("authToken"),
            user: null
        }  

        default:
            return state
    }
}


export default auth
```

Comment: Initial redux state of `isAuthenticated` maybe false.

Comment: yes. @GokulaKannanT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `componentDidMount()` is too late.
`<App/>` is already rendered with initial values when (user is not authenticated) and `<PrivateRoute/>` forces `<Redirect/>`.

**You need to load and process token during store initialization**.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: create store... initial state ... somewhere defined ... I don't see your code

Comment: Thers's a store.

Comment: should be in redux :D

Comment: check auth reducer

Comment: added auth reducer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207165/discussion-between-metalheaddev-and-xadm).

Comment: partially done ... load from localStorage in initialState .... if token in storage update `initialState` (just after definition) to be equal to `TOKEN_VERIFICATION_STARTS` state ... in user reducer the same, get token, if exists modify user `initialState` as equal to dispatching `getCurrentUser(authToken)` action